# PyQGIS: Zonal statistics not being written due to too many digits

Tags: pyqgis, zonal-statistics

I am using Python in QGIS to calculate zonal (sum) statistics for an array of raster layers using the following code:

```
polygonLayer  = QgsVectorLayer('E:/folder/' + 'gadm0.shp','','ogr')
rasterFilePath = "E:/folder" + r'/merged' + str(x) + '_R.tif'

polygonLayer.startEditing()
zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (polygonLayer, rasterFilePath, str(x), 1, QgsZonalStatistics.Sum)
zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
polygonLayer.commitChanges()
```

However, during the code I get some warnings like "value x not successfully written for feature z, possibly due to too larger number with respect to field width". I guess this is owing to the fact that shapefiles have a limit in the number of digits each field can contain.

When I open the attribute table of the output shapefile, I notice that:

1) a number of features have 0 as the output value, which does not make sense and thus I guess are those affected by the error.
2) successfully written features have way too many decimal digits than those I need.

How can I round the sum statistic to avoid data loss and useless decimal digits?